# Is there an old saying/joke about "Where would I go if I were a [name of lost object]?"

Tags: expressions, popular-refrains

In the 1950s my mother used to say, if I lost (for example) a glove, "Where would you go if you were a glove?" More recently I read this in a novel by my father from the mid-1960s: "... the old gag about looking for a lost dog. Where would I go if I were a dog?" Was this actually an expression people used (whether using the example of a dog or not)? I cannot find instances online.

Comment: I don't know how old it is, but this is a common trope. Google "[where would I hide if i were a](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=where+would+I+hide+if+i+were+a&atb=v104-2_g&ia=web)" and you'll see it's certainly not new or unique.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I have never heard anyone say this except my parents.

Comment: My parents said "Where would you *be* if you were a...?" At least that's how I remember it, but I'm a purist, and I recognize that something can be somewhere without going there. The answer, of course, is that you will find it in the last place you would ever look.  (Because, having found it, you look no further, so the place you found it becomes, by definition, the last place you would ever look for it.)

Comment: Your mother used it, so clearly it's an expression people used.